# Difference between 作り出す and 生み出す・生む

Tags: word-choice

Is this true?

- 作り出す　physically create something and make out of something already exist
- 生み出す・生む　metaphorically create something and make out of something from zero.

Comment: Like many things in language (maybe all things?), **context is key**.  Even simple words like はい and いいえ can have nuances depending on context.  Do you have any context for these words you're asking about?  Because depending on context, the answer to your question of _"is this true"_ might be "yes", and it might be "no".